# Realm.io and AFNetworking interaction

Tags: json, swift, afnetworking-2, realm

I have this request:

```
        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

        self.manager.POST(self.reservationsURL, parameters: reservation.parametersDictionary(), success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
            var responseObject = (operation.responseObject as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["data"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

//  responseObject = ["source": 1,
//                    "name": "Rodolfo",
//                    "info": "",
//                    "id": 160,
//                    "created": "2015-08-24T21:00:29Z",
//                    "people": 3,
//                    "datetime": "2015-08-24T21:00:29Z",
//                    "status": 0,
//                    "mobile": "11999999000",
//                    "modified": "2015-08-24T21:00:29Z"]

            self.realm.write { () -> Void in
                self.realm.create(GIReservation.self, value: parsedData, update: true)
            }

            }) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                println("OPS!\(operation.error)")
        }
```

And this model on Realm:

```
public class GIReservation: Object{
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var mobile = "" 
    dynamic var datetime = NSDate()
    dynamic var people = 0
    dynamic var status = 0
    dynamic var info = ""
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var localID = NSUUID().UUIDString
    dynamic var user: User?

    public func parametersDictionary() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        var parameters: [String : AnyObject] = ["name": self.name, "mobile": self.mobile, "datetime" : self.datetime.toUTCISO8601String(), "people" : self.people, "status" : self.status]

        if self.info.isEmpty {
            parameters["info"] = self.info
        }

        return parameters

    }

    public override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "localID"
    }
}
```

**The Problem:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value '3' for property 'people''

The same occurs on any other that isn't a String, so ok, I've checked that everything is returning a NCFString type, doesn't matter if it's a Int, or a Date.

Well the strange is; when I try the same thing with Objective-C and a RLMObject, it works like a charm.

The content-type of the JSON is application/json.

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that the `3` in the response dictionary is indeed a number rather than a string? Since the property on your `GIReservation` class is declared as being an `Int`

Comment: Yes, Im pretty sure, because the response works just fine in Objective-C.

Comment: In that case, and you share the ObjC code that's working for you?